# Javascript better way to code this animation

Tags: javascript

I first off all tried passing around the value of y back on the function but this caused the browser to slow as if an infinite loop had been created, the external frame variable stops this but I'd prefer to keep all the variables inside functions, is there a way I can achieve this without getting 'feedback'?

```
var frame=0;

function launch(){

var el=document.getElementById("selection");

setInterval(function(){ drawer(el,frame);},300);

}

function drawer(el,y){

if(y<20){
frame++;
el.style.top=20+frame+"px";
setInterval(function(){ drawer(el,frame);},300);

}
```

Comment: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: Do you have to solve this again in JavaScript or can you use CSS transitions?

Comment: jQuery...Very funny but no.

Comment: CSS transitions are not supported in IE 9.

Comment: use TweenMaxJS for js animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a closure, you also want to be using setTimeout or alternatively killing the interval when it's done:

```
function launch(){

    var animator = function(el) {
      var frame = 0;
      var _this = {
         draw : function() {
            frame += 1;
            el.style.top=20+frame+"px";
            if(frame < 20) {
                setTimeout(_this.draw, 300);
            }
         }
      }

      return _this;

    }(document.getElementById("selection"));

    setTimeout(animator.draw, 300);
}
```

Comment: thanks that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code. You only have to create an interval once. Store it in a variable and clear it when the maximum is reached.

```
var frame = 0;
var running = null;
var max = 20;
var e = document.getElementById("selection");

function drawer() {
    ++frame
    e.style.top = 20 + frame + "px";
    
    if (frame == max) {
        clearInterval(running);
        running = null;
    }
}

running = setInterval(drawer, 300);
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/EAmeT/)

### Edit

As you said in your question you want to keep all variables inside the function, you can use this:

```
function drawer(e, frame) {
    if ('undefined' == typeof e) {
        var e = document.getElementById("selection");
    }

    if ('undefined' == typeof frame) {
        var frame = 0;
    }
    
    ++frame
    e.style.top = 20 + frame + "px";
    
    if (frame <= 20) {
        setTimeout(function() { drawer(e, frame); }, 300);
    }
}
                   
drawer();
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/Bn2By/)

Comment: `function() { drawer(); }` can be replaced with `drawer`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few advices for you to improve your coding style:

- Try to make a meaningful functions
- Try to parametize numbers with meaningful and clear names
- Write clean codes

Let me give you my version of what I understand you are trying to do.
As you can see, it is more clean and easy to read/understand for others.

I included a live demo at the bottom for you to fiddle with.

```
function launch() {
    var el = document.getElementById('selection'),
        maxY = 300,
        stepY = 20,
        interval = 100;
    animateY(el, maxY, stepY, interval);
}

function moveToY(el, y) {
    el.style.top = y + "px";
}

function animateY(el, maxY, stepY, interval) {
    var y = 0;
    var id = setInterval(function () {
        if (y < maxY) {
            y += stepY;
            moveToY(el, y);
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(id);
        }
    }, interval);
}
```

Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A53sy/2/